# Stubborn Error 28 Out of Stack space in Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, stack

Been battling this error message for the past 2 weeks. I'v read the other posts about that and cleaned up my code, but i still get it.

Here's the first part of my code:

```
    Public PrevMinute As Integer
Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long


Sub Main()

PrevMinute = 0
Update
'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Main"


End Sub

Sub Update()

Ticker
WaitTime (3)

BookGet
WaitTime (3)

TradesGet
WaitTime (3)

CheckBuySellSignal
WaitTime (3)

Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Save

CheckTime

End Sub

Sub CheckTime()
NowMinute = Minute(Now)
If NowMinute <> PrevMinute Then
    PrevMinute = NowMinute
    Call Update
    Exit Sub
End If
WaitTime (5)
CheckTime

End Sub

Sub WaitTime(Finish As Long)

    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long

    EndTick = GetTickCount + (Finish * 1000)

    Do

        NowTick = GetTickCount
        DoEvents

    Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick

End Sub
```

And the second part where it fails on line TradesGet in the error handling part eh: I've added this error handling part to add error messages coming back from the server. Basically if i detect an error, i wait a few seconds and try again. AFter 3 tries i stop trying for that cycle (1 minute) copy/paste the data from the previous minute highlight the problematic values, and start all over again.

Basically i have the Checktime() sub that calls the Update() sub at the start of every minute. Update() sub calls 4 subs one after the other, the one that comes back with error is TradesGet sub when the server starts to throw errors (it also throws errors for the previous sub BookGet but this one goes though ok.

```
Sub TradesGet()

On Error GoTo eh

Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://api.gdax.com/products/ETH-EUR/trades"
MyRequest.Send

Set ParsedTrades = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)

'to try to fight intermitent bug
Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(19, "U") = MyRequest.ResponseText
WaitTime (2)

'check if did not receive error string from exchange, if so, start again (i should add logger here)
Dim pos As Integer
pos = InStr(MyRequest.ResponseText, "message")
If pos > 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Trades: received error message...retrying in 10 seconds"
    WaitTime (10)
    Application.StatusBar = "..retrying..."
    WaitTime (1)
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    TradesGet
    Exit Sub
End If


    'to speed up execution when looping
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

For i = 1 To 100

        'check if new tradeid > last tradeid, if so, copy
        LastTradeId = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(2, "B")
        If ParsedTrades(i)("trade_id") > LastTradeId Then

            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 15) = ParsedTrades(i)("time")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 16) = ParsedTrades(i)("trade_id")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 17) = ParsedTrades(i)("price")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 18) = ParsedTrades(i)("size")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 19) = ParsedTrades(i)("side")

        End If

Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True


  'move new data at the end of previous data and sort again
  Offset = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(1, "M").Value + 1
  OffsetNew = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(1, "N").Value + 1
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Range(Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(2, 15), Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(OffsetNew, "S")).Copy
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Range(Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(Offset, "A"), Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells((Offset + OffsetNew - 2), "E")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  'clear content of new data range to prepare for next cycle
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Range(Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(2, 15), Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(OffsetNew, "S")).ClearContents

  'sort data range to get latest tradeid number in cell B2
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Columns("A:E").Sort key1:=Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Range("B:B"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes


  'copy trades rates to ticker table
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Range("J3:K3").Copy
  Offset = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(1, "I").Value
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset, "S").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  'copy VSd to ticker table
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("book").Range("M26").Copy
  Offset = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(1, "I").Value
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset, "AI").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  'take snapshot of book t0
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("book").Range("N8:N9").Copy
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("book").Range("Q8:Q9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("book").Range("N15").Copy
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("book").Range("Q15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  'delete unused trades data beyond 15min
  DeleteLim = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(1, "L").Value
  Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Range(Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells((DeleteLim + 500), "A"), Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(2500, "E")).ClearContents


  'move focus back to ticker sheet
   Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Activate


Done:
    Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(13, "K") = 0
    Exit Sub

'error handling code, restart sub
eh:

    Application.StatusBar = "Trades: unexpected error ...retrying in 20 seconds"
    WaitTime (20)
    Application.StatusBar = "..retrying..."
    WaitTime (1)
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    'increase error counter by 1
    Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(13, "K") = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(13, "K") + 1
    'if error counter > 3, copy paste from previous minute, highlight in blue, and continue to CheckBuySellSignal, else run TradesGet again
    If Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(13, "K") < 3 Then
        TradesGet
        'Exit Sub
    Else
        Offset = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(1, "I").Value
        Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset, "S") = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset - 1, "S")
        Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset, "T") = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset - 1, "T")
        Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset, "S").Interior.ColorIndex = 28
        Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("ticker").Cells(Offset, "T").Interior.ColorIndex = 28
        'CheckBuySellSignal
        'Exit Sub
    End If
    Exit Sub




End Sub
```

Comment: That's a giant mountain of code. One approach to fix issues like this is to comment out chunks of it until it works, then systematically re-enable code until you find the exact line that causes it to break.

Comment: You should write much more about your error type, number, description, etc. Moreover, you should comment out `On Error GoTo...` to get real error and try to solve it first.

Comment: `CheckTime` calls either `CheckTime` or `Update` both of which call `CheckTime` which calls either `CheckTime` or `Update` both of which call `CheckTime` which calls either `CheckTime` or `Update` both of which call `CheckTime` (etc).  Of course it runs out of stack space.

Comment: And ditto for `TradesGet` - i.e. `TradesGet` often (?) calls `TradesGet` which often calls `TradesGet` which often calls `TradesGet` (etc)

Comment: Thanks all for the feed-back. I have commented out the eh: error handling. No change in behavior, still same error message : error 28 out of stack, coming from same place (not from eh: code). I have made a small modification to my CheckTime sub, i have added Exit Sub after calling CheckTime again. As i still had the same error message (less often ?) i have replaced the If/End If loop  that were calling TradesGet and BookGet again in case of error , by a Do While Loop instead. Now the only out of stack error i get is coming from sub JsonConverter (which i did not write myself). Will come back.

Comment: There is no point in placing an `Exit Sub` after calling `CheckTime` because the code never returns from `CheckTime` because `CheckTime` calls `CheckTime` calls `CheckTime` etc until you have no stack space left to make any more calls.  (And an `Exit Sub` immediately prior to an `End Sub` is pointless in **any** situation.)

Comment: ok. But this code has to run 24/7 at the top of every minute, so what is another way to do this rather than my CheckTime sub ? (I'm not 100% sure it's my CheckTime sub that is causing the out of stack, as i would normally have the error message on a regular basis after so many minutes, no ?) Now i have it now and then when the server returns some error messages. But I maybe wrong.

Comment: If you want something to run every minute, I would recommend you schedule it using `Application.OnTime`.

Comment: Is there a way to see what has gone onto the stack ? I mean, i would like to see which part of my code is piling up.

Comment: Yes - from the menu you can select View / Call Stack

Comment: ok, found the stack, thanks. Now, it was indeed CheckTime and Update that were piling up. So instead of calling them again, i'm now using Goto's. I know, I'm trying to wash my sins by committing more sins with these Goto clauses. But at present i don't have anything piling up in my stack, i only see one instance of Update and one for WaitTime (which was looping when i paused the code. So for lack of a better option, I'm gonna leave it like this for now. Thanks all.